# Allowing large results when using BigQueryIO in Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to  perform processing of rows from a table which includes roughly two billion rows using Dataflow, but my job fails while reading from BigQuery with the following error message:

```
error: Resources exceeded during query execution.
```

The reading part of my pipeline looks something like this:

```
DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
options.setProject(project);
options.setStagingLocation(staging_location);
options.setRunner(DataflowPipelineRunner.class);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

PCollection<TableRow> rows = p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery(query))
```

Is it possible to run BigQuery queries using BigQueryIO and allowing large results?

Comment: How many workers/VMs are you spinning up in the cluster? I don't see them being set in your code snippet...

Comment: Three, but i don't set the number of workers manually but let Dataflow decide instead. Would increasing the number of workers affect the Bigquery read?

Comment: We read similar amounts of data from BigQuery without any issues. But we know that we're reading a lot at the start so we start the cluster with like 32VMs or so. Do you actually need to a query (for which you'll be charged) or can you just use the standard BigQueryIO.Read.from([TABLE_SPEC])?

Comment: My guess the problem is in the query - can you share the query here? (and/or job id for the eng team)

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I cant share the query here, but an example of a job that fails with this error is 2016-07-14_02_41_38-16239600324432547753, and the only thing i change in the query between a successful and failing job is a limit.

Comment: How do you change the limit? Up, down,...?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa By increasing the limit in one of the subqueries / removing it altogether the query will fail with the following message `BigQuery job [bq-job-name] in project [project-name] finished with error(s): errorResult: Resources exceeded during query execution., error: Resources exceeded during query execution.`

Comment: Can you share the query please? Also, the table(s) size it's hitting.